# ValueError with sklearn metrics.average_precision_score

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn

I'm trying to use metrics.average_precision_score to calculate the average_precision of my sklearn KNN model, my code is like this:

```
average_precision = metrics.average_precision_score(y_test.values, np.array(y_pre.tolist))
```

But I get this error:

```
...
File "C:\My software\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_ranking.py", line 211, in average_precision_score
    "y_true." % pos_label)
ValueError: pos_label=1 is invalid. Set it to a label in y_true.
```

To check my y_test and y_pre, I used:

```
print(type(y_test))
print(type(y_test.values))
print(type(y_pre))
print(y_test.values)
print(y_pre)
```

I got result:

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
[3 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 2 2 3 3 2 3 3 3 2 3 2 3 3 3 2 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 3 2 3 3
 3 3 2 3 2 3 3 2 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 3
 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 2 3 2 3 3 2 2 3
 2 3 2 2 3 2 3 3]
[3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3]
```

I have no idea why this can't work, please help me, thank you.

Comment: There is indeed no label `1` in your predictions or test data, only `2` and `3`. What is your positive label?

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize this, it works after I change pos_label to 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map your labels to `0` and `1` in `y_test.values` and `y_pre` instead of `3` and `2`.

Remember: `1` must be the positive label.

Comment: Thank you, the test data given to me only have label 2 and 3, it works after I change pos_label to 3.